# c# class factory newbie

Tags: c#, class, factory

This may be the wrong title for what I am looking for, but I *think* it boils down to a class factory.

I have three classes:

```
   class Horse : Animal
   class Cow :   Animal
```

What I want to create is a method in Animal that, pseudocoded, would work like this:

```
   List<Horse or Cow> (Animal horseOrCow)
   {
      if (horseOrCow is of type Horse)
         return a list of 10 Horse objects; 
      else
         return a list of 10 Cow objects;
   }
```

A simplification of course, but once I grasp how to do this, I should be able to figure out the rest.

(Edit: Typo fixed).

Comment: This is way too vague. What is the bigger and more concrete picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`is`-operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `Enumerable.OfType` + `Enumerable.Take`:

```
public List<Animal> getMammals(Mammal horseOrCow)
{
    if (horseOrCow is Horse)
        return allAnimals.OfType<Horse>().Take(10).Cast<Animal>().ToList();
    else if (horseOrCow is Cow)
        return allAnimals.OfType<Cow>().Take(10).Cast<Animal>().ToList();
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Mammal", "horseOrCow");
}
```

assuming that there is a `List<Animal> allAnimals`somewhere.

**Edit**: `Mammal` must also be an `Animal` and since `Horse` and `Cow` are `Mammals` they should inherit from it.

```
class Horse : Mammal{ }
class Cow : Mammal { }
class Animal { }
class Mammal : Animal { }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**generic method of type**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

```
List<T> YourMethod<T>(T horseOrCow) where  T : Mamal
{
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
abstract class Animal
abstract class Mammal : Animal  
class Horse : Mammal 
class Cow :   Mammal 

List<T> (T mammal) where  T : Mammal  //mammal is cow or horse
{
   if (horseOrCow is Horse)
      return new List<Horse>(); //add the horses to your list 
   else
      return new List<Cow>(); //add the cows to your list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Animal
{
    public List<Mammal> GetMammalList(Mammal mammal)
    {
        List<Mammal> list = new List<Mammal>();
        if (mammal.GetType() == typeof(Horse))
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                list.Add(new Horse());
        else if (mammal.GetType() == typeof(Cow))
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                list.Add(new Cow());
        else
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        return list;
    }
}

public class Mammal : Animal { }

public class Horse : Mammal { }

public class Cow : Mammal { }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would NOT recommend type checking using `is`.  Rather use `dynamic` to determine the runtime type of the object.

```
public void List<T> GetMammals<T>(T mammal) where  T : Mammal
{
   GetMammalsSpecialization(mammal as dynamic);
}

private void List<Horse> GetMammalsSpecialization(Horse horse)
{
    // Specialized code to return list of horses
}

private void List<Cow> GetMammalsSpecialization(Cow cow)
{
    // Specialized code to return list of cows
}
```

This is a better solution to the [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) problem.

Comment: Having a generic class factory isn't a great idea in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Animal
{ 
   public enum AnimalType
   {
     CowType,
     HorseType
   }


   ....
   public Animal Create(AnimalType type)
   {
     Animal result = null;
      switch (type)
      {
       case HorseType: result = new Horse();
       case CowType : ....   
      }
     return result;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think he may need to pass in an actual Horse or Cow.  OP confirm?

Comment: This is a class factory and this is a one way of its implementation.

Comment: A superclass should never know about their subclasses.

Comment: This is not a super class this is the abstract factory, abstract factory method. So, please deal with issue before marking answer down.